# Mac OS X Internet Recovery Questions

Tags: macos, mac, ssd

I have recently upgraded a MacBook Pro 2011 13" with a new Samsung EVO 850 240GB SSD and am using the Mac OS X Internet Recovery feature for the first time. The previous disk was the original HDD that had been updated to OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

**A few questions:**

**1. Auto Boot To Internet Recovery**

I have seen guides mention that if OS X is not detected on the disk, it will automatically boot into Recovery or Internet Recovery. In my case, after the 'Mac chime' it went to a white screen that continuously flashed a question mark box. Why is this? I assume it is because my 2011 MacBook is too old for this auto recovery feature? Would it have anything to do with the SSD not being formatted?

**2. WiFi Password Recovery**

After booting and using **Option + Command + R** to enter Internet Recovery, most guides mention that it should prompt for network settings (wifi network to join and password). In my case, it skipped this step. I am guessing that the MacBook/OS X has stored my previous WiFi settings somewhere?

**3. Timer**

Out of curiosity, I am guessing that the timer displayed during Internet Recovery is the current estimated time to complete downloading the latest version of OS X for installation and to enable the other recovery options. Is this correct?

I only have two weeks of OS X experience so forgive me if these are trivial questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) Only Macs that came with OS X 10.7.0 or newer have the ability for Internet Recovery built in.  Your 2011 likely came with a variant of 10.6 which was the last OS to ship with a disc and the first with the App Store. In your case, your new SSD usually will come unpartitioned, no Recovery disc or any other OS related things on it, a true blank slate. So yes, your drive came unformatted and the flashing folder is showing the computer didn't find a bootable operating system on any disk.

2) Normally command-option-R wouldn't work on a machine of your year without at least another Recovery partition present. Do you have any other drives attached?  If you had a Recovery partition available, command-R would have booted to that. You can hold option at boot until you see the pointer and it will graphically show all available bootable partitions. My guess is there's a Recovery partition on another drive somewhere. It shouldn't be keeping any wifi keys or networks anywhere but the OS you've used it on before. This is what makes me think there's a regular Recovery partition somewhere.

3) The timer is the download time for the NetBoot image. Once that finishes then the real boot up starts to Internet Recovery.